# Evaluation of a particular type of integral involving logs and trigonometric function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is there any closed form for 
$$ \int _0 ^{\infty}\int _0 ^{\infty}\int _0 ^{\infty} \log(x)\log(y)\log(z)\cos(x^2+y^2+z^2)dzdydx$$
if yes then how to prove it?

Comment: If I had asked this question, I would consider accepting @FelixMarin's answer instead, as he got the correct answer independently and corrected a long-standing error in my answer.

Comment: @RonGordon I'll do it right a way ..I tough I had done it a few hours ago ..As this was just out of curiosity .... I never tried to numerically verify your result actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
     \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{z}\cos\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}
     \,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{z}\cos\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}
> \,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\Re\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{z}\expo{\ic\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}}
> \,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\Re\pars{\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\expo{\ic x^{2}}\,\dd x}^{3}}
> ={1 \over 64}\,\Re\pars{\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\ln\pars{x}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}^{3}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 64}\,\Re\pars{\bracks{\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}}^{3}}
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad -1 < \mu < 0\tag{1}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{\ic x \equiv -t\quad\imp\quad x = \ic t}$
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}
=\expo{\pi\mu\ic/2}\int_{0}^{-\infty\ic}t^{\mu}\expo{-t}\ic\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\ic\expo{\pi\mu\ic/2}\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\mu}\expo{-t}\,\dd x
-\lim_{R \to \infty}
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ R\atop
      {\vphantom{\Huge A} -\pi/2\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ 0}}
z^{\mu}\expo{-z}\,\dd z}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> However,
>   \begin{align}&0 < \verts{\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ R\atop
> {\vphantom{\Huge A} -\pi/2\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ 0}}z^{\mu}\expo{-z}\,\dd z}
> <\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}R^{\mu}\exp\pars{-R\cos\pars{\theta}}R\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=R^{\mu + 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> <R^{\mu + 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-2R\theta/\pi}\,\dd\theta
> ={\pi \over 2}\,R^{\mu}\pars{1 - \expo{-R}}
> \end{align}

Then,
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty}
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ R\atop
      {\vphantom{\Huge A} -\pi/2\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ 0}}
z^{\mu}\expo{-z}\,\dd z = 0
\quad\mbox{since}\quad \mu <0.
$$
and, from expression $\pars{2}$,
$$
\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}
=\ic\expo{\pi\mu\ic/2}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
$$
where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$. Also
$$\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}
=-\,{\pi \over 2}\,\expo{-\pi\ic/4}\Gamma\pars{\half}
+\ic\expo{-\pi\ic/4}\Gamma\pars{\half}\Psi\pars{\half}\tag{3}
$$
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$.

With $\ds{\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}}$
( [see](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.8}}$ ) and $\ds{\Psi\pars{\half} = -\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}}$
( [see](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.3}}$ ),
expression $\pars{3}$ is reduced to:
$$
\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}
=-\expo{-\pi\ic/4}\root{\pi}\braces{{\pi \over 2}
+\bracks{\gamma + 2\ln\pars{2}}\ic}\tag{4}
$$
$\ds{\gamma}$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.3}}$.

> With $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{4}$ we find:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{z}\cos\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}
> \,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&={\pi^{3/2} \over 64}\,\Re\pars{\pars{%
> -\expo{-\pi\ic/4}\braces{{\pi \over 2} +\bracks{\gamma + 2\ln\pars{2}}\ic}}^{3}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{2}\pi^{3/2} \over 2048}
> \Re\pars{\braces{\bracks{1 - \ic}\bracks{\pi + \varphi\ic}}^{3}}
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad\varphi\equiv 2\bracks{\gamma + 2\ln\pars{2}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{z}\cos\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}
\,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{2}\pi^{3/2} \over 1024}
\Re\pars{\bracks{-1 - \ic}\bracks{\pi + \varphi\ic}^{3}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{2}\pi^{3/2} \over 1024}
\Re\pars{\bracks{-1 - \ic}
\braces{\pi\bracks{\pi^{2} - 3\varphi^{2}}+
\bracks{3\pi^{2} - \varphi^{2}}\varphi\ic}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{2}\pi^{3/2} \over 1024}\braces{%
\pi\bracks{3\varphi^{2} - \pi^{2}} + \bracks{3\pi^{2} - \varphi^{2}}\varphi}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{2}\pi^{3/2} \over 1024}\pars{%
-\varphi^{3} + 3\pi\varphi^{2} + 3\pi^{2}\varphi - \pi^{3}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#44f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{z}\cos\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}
> \,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#44f}{\large-\,{\root{2}\pi^{3/2} \over 1024}
> \pars{\pi + \varphi}\bracks{\pars{2 - \root{3}}\pi - \varphi}
> \bracks{\pars{-2 - \root{3}}\pi + \varphi}}
> \\[3mm]&\approx -1.3077\,,\qquad\qquad \varphi \equiv 2\bracks{\gamma + 2\ln\pars{2}}
> \end{align}

Comment: Martin such a wonderfull proof ..I liked the way you used complex as well as real analysis .

Comment: @ShivamPatel Thanks. You're welcome. I like very much your posts.

Answer (score 8):

One way to attack this is to exploit the symmetry of the integral.  Start by expanding the cosine term into individual pieces, i.e.,

$$\begin{align}\cos{(x^2+y^2+z^2)} &= \cos{x^2} \cos{(y^2+z^2)} - \sin{x^2} \sin{(y^2+z^2)}\\ &= \cos{x^2} \cos{y^2} \cos{z^2} - \cos{x^2} \sin{y^2} \sin{z^2}  \\ &\quad -\sin{x^2} \sin{y^2} \cos{z^2} - \sin{x^2} \cos{y^2} \sin{z^2} \end{align}$$

Next define

$$C = \int_0^{\infty} dx \, \cos{x^2} \: \log{x} $$
$$S = \int_0^{\infty} dx \, \sin{x^2} \: \log{x} $$

Then the triple integral is equal to $C^3-3 C S^2$.

We obtain $C$ and $S$ using Cauchy's theorem to find $C+i S$.  We do this by considering the integral

$$\oint_{\eta} dz \, e^{i z^2} \log{z}$$

where $\eta$ is a circular wedge of radius $R$ and angle $\pi/4$ in the upper half plane with base along the positive real axis.  One may show that the integral over the circular arc vanishes as $\pi \log{R}/(4 R)$ as $R \to \infty$.  Thus, we have

$$C+i S = e^{i \pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2} \left (\log{t} + i \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) $$

One may derive the value of this integral by noting that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2} \log{t} = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} (\gamma + 2 \log{2})$$

This value is derived from using the value of

$$\frac12 \left [\frac{d}{d\alpha} \Gamma \left (\frac{\alpha+1}{2} \right ) \right ]_{\alpha=0} = \frac14 \Gamma \left (\frac12 \right ) \psi \left ( \frac12 \right )$$

We also use

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

to obtain

$$C = -\frac18 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\pi + 2 \gamma + 4 \log{2})$$
$$S = \frac18 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\pi - 2 \gamma - 4 \log{2})$$

and therefore the triple integral is

$$C^3-3 C S^2 = \frac{\pi ^{3/2} \left(4 \gamma ^2-8 \gamma  \pi +\pi ^2+16 \log{2} \,(\gamma
   -\pi +\log{2})\right) (2 \gamma +\pi +4 \log{2})}{512 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I guess you have a typo somewhere. Your result is $\approx -1.3413$ but Mathematica evaluates the integral and yields $\approx -1.3077$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Thank you for catching my mistake.  I made a sign error that I should have caught.  (The lack of a factor of 3 should have raised an alert.)  I have corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, solving
$$J(a):=\int_0^\infty \log(x) \cos(x^2 + a) dx$$
with Maple yields
$$J(a) = -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{16} (4\log 2 \cos(a) + 2\cos(a) \gamma + \cos(a) \pi - 4\log 2 \sin(a) - 2\sin(a) \gamma + \sin(a) \pi)$$
Wich gives hope toward the existence of the integral, since
$$I = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \log x \log y J(x^2 + y^2)\ dy\ dx$$
And $J$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\cos(a)$ and $\cos(a + \frac{\pi}2) = \sin(a)$, so
$$\int \log x J(x^2+y^2) dx = \sum_i \lambda_i J(?_i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\log x \rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, try proving that this integral does not exist (due to the oscilation the $\cos$ factor brings along.

Comment: Actually, both the negative and positive regions of the integral are infinite.  Typically, we would only be able to say that this is not integrable.

Comment: @Gaffney Good god, I completely ignored the cosine in the function. Thank you for the correction.